# Core Data iOS app crashes when getting the context

Tags: ios, core-data, crash, chat, quickblox

I use Quickblox for my chatting app and use core data to store message history.

When I log in to the chat, I resend messages that was failed to send last time. (i.e. I fetch messages from Core Data and get the unsent ones)

Some times it works, but some times the app crashes on the helper method (which is used to get the Core Data context):

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    return ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;
}
```

I didn't change anything for App Delegate, it's just a normal CoreData enabled AppDelegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, QBActionStatusDelegate, QBChatDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;


@end
```

This is how I retrieve a message history in a DBHelper class

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)fetchMessagesWithSenderID:(NSString *)userID {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Message" inManagedObjectContext:[DBHelper context]]; //the app crashes here, inside [DBHelper context]
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sender.userID = %@", userID];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];


    NSError *error;

    NSMutableArray *fetchedObjects = [[DBHelper context] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error].mutableCopy;
    return fetchedObjects;
}
```

Log:

```
2014-01-05 16:32:05.365 Chat[1517:60b] completedWithResult: <QBMRegisterSubscriptionTaskResult: 0x14e955e0>
2014-01-05 16:32:05.366 Chat[1517:60b] error: (
    "Invalid provisioning profiles. You have to use valid Provisioning Profiles for your project"
)
2014-01-05 16:32:06.549 Chat[1517:180f] QBChat/didConnect
2014-01-05 16:32:07.913 Chat[1517:4103] -[QBChat xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:] -> user: 573782, supportsStartTLS: 1, isSecure: 0
2014-01-05 16:32:07.913 Chat[1517:60b] chatDidLogin
2014-01-05 16:32:07.916 Chat[1517:60b] -[QBMGetTokenPerformer managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d48800
(lldb)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move all CoreData logic from AppDelegate to separate singleton:

***.h file:**

```
@interface CoreDataService : NSObject

 +(instancetype)instance;
 - (void)saveContext;

@end
```

***.m file:**

```
@implementation CoreDataService

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext
*managedObjectContext;  
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;    
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
*persistentStoreCoordinator;

 - (void)saveContext{   
 ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> -[QBMGetTokenPerformer managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d48800

This line means that you've called the `managedObjectContext` method on an object of class `QBMGetTokenPerformer`, which doesn't recognise that method.

From the code in your question and the screenshots you've shown, this shouldn't be happening - I don't know how a call to the app delegate could *sometimes* return an unrelated object - the only time I've seen this happen is due to memory management issues, but the app delegate is effectively a singleton so its memory can't be reassigned.

All I can suggest is that you add an exception breakpoint to your app - though it looks like you already have one in place. You could perhaps break out your method into separate lines so you can see what is happening on each one.

Comment: Memory management issues could cause AppDelegate to be overwritten in memory, so it is still possible, however unlikely.

Comment: QBMGetTokenPerformer is from QuickBlox, but I don't think it calls any core data methods. (QuickBlox is just a chatting framework that does not requires Core Data)

Comment: @OMGPOP - I realise that, that's what the problem is. Somehow you're asking the wrong object for a managedObjectContext, so you must be getting the wrong object back when asking for your app delegate.